# Read data from HttpWebRequest asynchronously (as long as a new response is detected)?

Tags: c#, .net, json, asynchronous

We have been given a uri which throws JSON responses repeatedly:
https://live.wh.sportingpulseinternational.com/v1/basketball/read/448426?ak=6eea426648c256cae71a9409352304fe&types=scoreboard,status,boxscore&format=json

Now our goal is to asynchronously fetch the JSON data (store as a string and as long as a new response is detected). The previous project relied only on time intervals in fetching data but they want it done asynchronously.

Sorry I'm a noob when it comes to asynchronous programming and I need help.

I've read about HttpWebRequest and I'm not very sure if this is the right tool to use, any simpler way for this simple task is welcome.

Comment: HttpWebRequest is connection less and survives per web request unless it is singleton, so I guess long polling is the only option left, i.e. already implement as you mentioned. please correct me if I don't understand the question correctly.

Comment: Would you be able to share how you implemented yours?